# Why can't we produce energy from gravity

Tags: energy, particle-physics, gravity, energy-conservation

Yes, we know how to create electricity (or at least another energy) out of fire, water and air, but why we can't create electricity from gravitational force.
For instance, someone sitting on a chair that glows as bright as the sitting person's weight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually we do create energy out of gravity, that is the whole principle behind [hydroelectricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroelectricity): *drop* water into a turbine!

The gravitational potential energy is transformed into kinetic energy, which is used to make turbine rotate and induce an electric potential

Comment: Doesn't it waste energy to lift the water before it drops, or a constantly moving water (from a waterfall for example) is dependent on another energy too. So it is not only gravity ? Take my chair example. This is equal to the person sitting on that chair jump on it, to make any effect.

Comment: Not really, dams are built for that reason

Comment: what is dams though. Surely it's not damselflies

Comment: @Edenia [Just](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dam) imagine poking a hole  along the wall, the water will drop into the blades of the turbine and will make them rotate

Comment: So in order to get energy from gravity.. the object influenced must move.
If I understood the concept correctly.

Comment: @Edenia You are right

Comment: Though I don't get why we can't obtain it by staying still as the gravity still acts on us. The only difference, according to the laws of conversion, is that if we jump (for example) we basically "feed" the gravity with energy.

Comment: Hydroelectrics are using gravity, but the *energy is supplied by the sun* in the series  process :evaporation, clouds, rain, water in high mountain lakes, dams and hydroelectric plants.

Answer (score 2):

We do not "create energy out of fire, water and air", we only extract it. According to the energy conservation law, energy is always the same, it cannot be created or destroyed (short of the redshift that is unrelated to your question). Energy only can be converted from one form to another. In your examples, fire, water and air contain the energy given to them earlier by the Sun. We burn wood of plants that grew under the sun. We extract *gravitational* energy from water that water gained by evaporating under the sunlight. We rotate windmills by air moving from higher pressure areas warmed by the sun. Once the sun energy is extracted from the elements, we cannot extract any more until the sun provides more energy to be stored in the elements again. You can easily extract gravitational energy from your weight by pushing pedals connected to a generator. However, same as with the elements, you can only do this once and then you'll have to do work to lift yourself up again.

---

To summarize, gravitation is a force, not an energy. Energy is force multiplied by distance. So you cannot extract energy from gravitation of a non-moving object the same way as you cannot rotate windmills by a non-moving air.